# How I build if statement if the column is exit in database or not (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

How I can write if the statement if the find the attachment in the column or not?

```
@if($request->pdfuplode)
<td> 
   <a href="{{ url('uploads/reports/'.$request->pdfuplode) }}" target="_blank"> 
   report
   </a>
</td>
@else
  <td> - </td>
```

I mean if the pdfuplode is not null will show the link pf report .. if it null show (-)

Comment: Use your databases `coalesce` function on the column in question?  What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: I have column pdfuplode in my table ... I need to check if it null or not .. if it null show (-) or if not null should show the link of pdfuploade .. the error is syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your question and we don't have enough information to answer it.  My first comment is the answer to your question.  The issue you are having sounds like you forgot the end if or something equally naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do an [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) check in your blade like so:

```
@if(empty($request->pdfuplode))
    <td> - </td>
@else
    <td> 
        <a href="{{ url('uploads/reports/'.$request->pdfuplode) }}" target="_blank"> 
            report
        </a>
    </td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to check whether the request contains your file or not

```
@if(!$result->isEmpty())
   // $array is not empty
@else
  // $array is empty
@endif
```

isEmpty() method will check if the array is null or not . if its not null then the if condition will run otherwise the else condition. You can make changing in the if else for your desired work.